# Not getting the Marker object that I expected

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

On the first `onLocationChanged` event allback I add a Marker with current location to my map and that method returns a `Marker` instance. I save that instance to a variable, but when I click on the marker's InfoWindow the Marker that is passed to me is a different object, therefore `if(savedMarker != marker)` always true.

Actual codes that are relevant:

onLocationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(mMyPos == null) {
        mMyPos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .title("MyPos")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationToLatLng(location), 15));
    }
    mMyPos.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
}
```

onInfoWindowClick:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            if(marker != mMyPos) {
                doSomething();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If I change the condition to `if(!marker.getTitle().equals(mMyPos.getTitle()))` it works, but I really don't like it that way. Any ideas?

Comment: if your marker id's are different then the marker clicked is not the one you have as your variable

Comment: yes, but what and why changes it? also mMyPos is only touched in the codes that I show.

Comment: `mMyPos` changes every time your location changes and you dont remove the old marker, you probably have a few markers stacked upon each other and dont even know it

Comment: if `mMyPos` is not null, I only change it's position, I do not add a new Marker to the map

Comment: so try commenting out the line `mMyPos.setPosition` that way the marker never moves. if you click on the marker and its the correct information then you know using setPosition changes the marker

Comment: Good idea, will try!

Comment: you should also have that line in an `else` block because in the case where mMyPos is null you set the position twice

Comment: It looks like that when the `onInfoWindowClick()` is called, a new `Marker` is created. In the source it looks like this `listener.onInfoWindowClick(new Marker(var1));` So yeah, I'm just getting like a clone of that `Marker` sadly. And yup, I was thinking about that alse block too, changed it, thanks!

Comment: Bit of clarification after a bit more source checking, what I think is that the class `Marker` is just some kind of wrapper class (around some obfuscated interface), and it's "`MarkerOptions`" is passed around that's why it stays the same, and the reason why we can modify the same `Marker` on the map with different instances of it.